# Passing char by reference

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

The problem is that I am trying to pass a sentence by reference to change something about it(this case adding a character), but nothing is changed.

The first thing I tried was this original code but without putting in any "*" or "&" and I got the same output. I have read other similar questions that have used strcpy() but I am not sure how that might apply to this problem or what the solution might be as I am unfamiliar with pointers used in this way.

```
char my_char_func(char *x)
{
    return x+'c';
}
int main()
{
    char (*foo)(char);
    foo = &my_char_func;
    char word[]="print this out";
    puts(word);
    foo(&word);
    puts(word);
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the second output to be "print this outc"

Comment: `foo = &my_char_func;` is an error. If you don't get an error message then adjust your compiler settings.  `foo(&word)` is also an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the character c to the actual pointer. As you can't dynamically expand your character array in C, I believe you're going to have to malloc a new array with space for the extra character, delete the pointer being passed in, and then set it the beginning of the new array. That should avoid memory overrun.

```
int main()
{
    char (*foo)(char);
    int i = 0;
    foo = &my_char_func;
    char word[]="print this out";
    for(i = 0; i < size_of(word); ++i)
    {
       word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
    }
    puts(word);
    foo(&word);
    puts(word);
    return 0;
}

If you don't want to use toUpper, you can change you function in either of two ways:

Option 1:

void my_char_func(char *string, int sizeOfString)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeOfString; ++i)
    {
        //Insert logic here for checking if character needs capitalization
        string[i] = string[i] + ' ';
    }
}

Option 2:
Do the same as with toUpper, simply calling your own function instead.
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I think that will work, but what if I am not adding a character but instead want to change the contents of the character array like instead of of "print this out" I want to change the text to "print out this", what could I have done?

Comment: As long as you're not overrunning the size of your array, you don't need to allocate a new array, you can use direct array access e.g: x[3] = 'c' or you can use pointer arithmetic *(x + 3) = 'c' , these both have the same effect. If you have a more general goal though, maybe I can help with that?

Comment: Thanks, I will make a new question about it.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't let me write up new question yet. But the code is pretty much the same except instead of "return (x+'c')" it is "return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - 'a' + 'A' : c);" which is suppose to change the message all to captial

Comment: And with the above change, it still prints the same message twice. So I tried this "strcpy(c,((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - 'a' + 'A' : c)); return (c);" but then it doesn't even print the second part out now

Comment: AH I see, so you're trying to capitalize everything?
You can use the toUpper function if that's easier for you, but let me post the code.